# php deleting Comment Reply using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, comments, delete-row

I will try to delete comment Reply,Which have 
    parent_id = 0

That is Fixed.I can Delete parent comment,But When I deleting Child comment(reply).The parent Comment Deleted but Not the child one.And The reply comment remain in the database and also shown in the page unless I refresh it.
I have function for get the comment and reply like this

```
        <?php
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
     require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
     include __DIR__.'/../lib/Database.php';
     include __DIR__.'/../config/config.php';
     include __DIR__.'/../lib/Session.php';
     include __DIR__.'/../helpers/Format.php';
     $db = new Database();
     $fm = new Format();
    ?>
        <?php
             $commentQuery = "SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE `parent_id`= '0' 
ORDER BY `id` DESC";
             $result = $db->select($commentQuery);
             $commentReply='';
            if($result) {
               while ($cmResult = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          ?>
           <?php
           $commentReply .= ' 
           <div class="panel-wrapper parent_wrapper" id = 
"'.$cmResult['id'].'">
           <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="fa-2x text-right" style="border: none;">    
          <button class=" btn bn-default delClick">             
      <span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:Mistyrose; border: 
none;">
        <i class="fa-inverse fas fa-times-circle" style="color: black;" 
data-fa-transform="shrink-3">
    </i>
      </span>
      </button>
      </div>                
        <div class="panel-heading">

                               <h4>
                                <span class= "fa-layers fa-fw">
                                <i class="fa-inverse fas fa-user-graduate fa-3x" style=" background:MistyRose">                         
    </i> </span>
      ' . $cmResult["sender"] . '                   </h4>                                                             
    <p class="date">' . $fm->DateFormat($cmResult["date"]) . '</p>
      </div> 
      <div class="panel-body">              
      <p class="comment">'.$fm->textShorten($cmResult["comment"],70).'</p>
         <button type="button"  class="btn btn-warning reply" id="' . $cmResult["id"] . '">REPLY</button>
         </div>                        
         </div>
         </div>';
        ?>
    <?php
        $commentReply .= getReply($db,$fm,$cmResult['id']);
            }
            echo $commentReply;
        }
    ?>
    <?php
     function getReply($db,$fm,$parentId=0,$margin = 0)
     {
             //$fm = new  Format();
             //$db = new Database();
             $commentReply = '';
             $getQuery = "SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE `parent_id`='" . $parentId . "' ORDER BY `id` DESC";
             if( $result = $db->select($getQuery))
             {
              $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

         if($parentId== 0)
         {
             $margin = 0;
         }else
         {
             $margin = $margin + 28;
         }
         if(!empty($count)||$count>0)
         {
            while( $cmResult = $result->fetch_assoc())
               {
                   //$reply = 1;
        // $fm =new Format();
        $cmDate = $fm->DateFormat($cmResult['date']);
         $shorten = $fm->textShorten($cmResult['comment'],70);
         $commentReply.='
         <div class="panel-wrapper" style="margin-left: '. $margin. 'px" id = "'.$cmResult['id'].'">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="fa-2x text-right" style="border: none;">  
          <button class=" btn btn-default delClick">                
      <span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:Mistyrose; border: none;">
        <i class="fa-inverse fas fa-times-circle" style="color: black;" data-fa-transform="shrink-3">
    </i>
      </span>
      </button>
      </div>
         <div class="panel-heading">        
         <h4>
             <span class="fa-layers fa-fw">
                <i class="fa-inverse fas fa-user-graduate fa-3x" data-fa-transform="shrink-8"
                    style="background:MistyRose">
                         </i>
                            </span>                         
                            '. $cmResult["sender"].'                          
                             </h4>
                             <p class="date">'.$cmDate.'</p>
                         </div>
                         <div class="panel-body">
                             <p class="comment">'. $shorten.'</p>
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning reply" id="'. $cmResult["id"].'">
                                 REPLY
                             </button>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>';
                 $commentReply .= getReply($db,$fm,$cmResult['id'],$margin);
             }
             }}
         return $commentReply;
     }
    ?>
```

I tried to delete the reply comment using ajax

```
$(document).on('click','.delClick',function (e) {
e.preventDefault(); 
        var element = $(this).parent().parent();
    var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
    url:"../scripts/disqus_template.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "id=" + del_id,
    dataType: "JSON",
    cache: false,
    success: function (response){          
        if(response.error) {             
            $('#delmessage').fadeIn('500').html(response.message);
            $('#delmessage').fadeOut('500').html(response.message);
            $('#delmessage').fadeIn('500').html(response.message);                      
            $('#delmessage').fadeOut('500').html(response.message);                      
            //$('#delmessage').fadeIn('500').html(response.message);                      
            //$('#delmessage').fadeOut('500').html(response.message);  
        element.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
    if($("#countNumber").length > 0) {
                    var currentCount = parseInt($("#countNumber").text());
                    var newCount = currentCount - 1;
                    $("#countNumber").text(newCount)
                }               
        }       
    }

    });
    return false;

   // return false;
});
```

php script for deleting comment like this->

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
include __DIR__.'/../lib/Session.php';
//include __DIR__.'/../scripts/disqus.php';
include __DIR__.'/../config/config.php';
include __DIR__.'/../lib/Database.php';
//Session:: init();
$db = new Database();

//var_dump($id);
//die();

 $commentQuery = "SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE `comment`.`parent_id`= 0";
 if(     $result = $db->select($commentQuery))
 {

    $delResult = mysqli_num_rows( $result);
    if(!empty($delResult)|| $delResult>0)
    {
    if($cmResult =$result ->fetch_assoc())
    {
    //$reply= 1;
    $id = $cmResult['id'];
    $parentId = $cmResult['parent_id'];

    if($id)
    {
    $delete = "DELETE  FROM comment WHERE `comment`.`id`='".$id."'";
    $result= $db->delete($delete);

    if($result)
    {
     $msg = "<p class='alert alert-success'>.<span class='fa-layers fa-fw'>. 
   <i class='fas fa-check-circle fa-2x'></i></span>success</p>";
    $status = array
    (
        'error' => 3,
        'message' => $msg
    );

    } else {
    $msg = "<p class='alert alert-danger'>.<i class='fas fa-times-circle fa- 
   2x'>.</i>deny</p>";
    $status = array
    (
        'error' => 4,
        'message' => $msg
    );
    }       

    }
     echo json_encode($status); 

    }

    }       
    }
```

But No luck with that.I think I have not getting a simple thing,which is blink on my eyes.

Comment: _"The reply comment remain in the database and also shown in the page unless I refresh it."_ - Does that mean that the comment _does_ get deleted but it won't _show_ until you refresh the page, or does it mean that it doesn't delete it at all? There's a big difference.

Comment: the comment reply remain in the database but parent get deleted,when I click on the button of the reply section.And before refreshing the page ,comment reply shown but parents are not.

Comment: I'm not getting your posted code. As far as I can see, the only thing that happens here is that you fetch all comments having parent 0. Then you're looping through all those comments and delete them, if their `id` isn't falsy (which id's usually aren't). The above code doesn't take into account what comment you're trying to delete. It looks like it always will delete all comments with parent id 0.

Comment: yes absolutely right.what i want is ,I can delete both parent and child individually.

Comment: Just pass the ID of the comment you want to delete and use that to filter your delete query.

Comment: you mean no need to fecth all the comment? just `parent_id`= "'.$id.'"?

Comment: When I've done comment systems and you can delete a comment, I usually only set a "deleted" flag on the comment in the database (so I don't actually remove it). Then, when listing comments, I usually change the text to "Deleted comment" instead if it has children (and not show it at all if it doesn't). Then you can still show the children (just because the parent was deleted doesn't mean that the children should be deleted. They can still contain valid comments).

Comment: You should also read up on parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries with user data.

Comment: The idea is not very much clear to me